# Hazelcast exception

Tags: hazelcast

We recently added Hazelcast to one of our applications and noticed this NPE coming in our logs without obvious reasons.
We are using Hazelcast 3.11 and there are twenty members in the cluster running on four physical servers.
We use Hazelcast to share some locks and a map across different JVMs.

```
[24/08/19 17:50:10:586 EST] 000000ba ExecutionServ E com.hazelcast.spi.ExecutionService  [SERVERNAME]:5701 [xyz] [3.11.3] Failed to execute java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@b20b531
                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hazelcast.crdt.CRDTReplicationTask.replicate(CRDTReplicationTask.java:101)
    at com.hazelcast.crdt.CRDTReplicationTask.run(CRDTReplicationTask.java:67)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.executionservice.impl.DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator$DelegateDecorator.run(DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator.java:77)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:929)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:773)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:64)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:80)
```

Given our application is very critical I would like to understand what would potentially cause it and what would be the consequences. Our application seems to be working normally around the places where we use Hazelcast.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to have been logged with Hazelcast and fixed in September 2018:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/13706

But it looks like the issue never made it into one of the hazelcast releases. See the release notes, no mention of bug 13706:
https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/rn/index.html#3-12-2

I asked if/when this issue will be released (if not already) on the hazecast pull request (1st link above).

One thing you could try, just in case they pulled the fix into one release, would be to test with hazelcast 3.12.2 (latest release), maybe they pulled in the fix but didn't mention it in the release notes?